# Environment variables are undefined when using Google Cloud Secret Manager in the Firebase Functions Emulator with --inspect-functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools, google-secret-manager

I added Firebase Functions secrets via the CLI [as described in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#secret-manager). The secrets are populated correctly in `process.env` both in deployed *and* emulated functions **UNLESS** the `--inspect-functions` flag is set. In that case, the secrets in `process.env` are `undefined` and no errors are displayed.

---

The issue only occurs when I run: `firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions`. Other notes:

- I have the correct permissions set for the service account and there are no permissions errors.
- I'm using `.runWith` correctly, since the same code works in the other environments. Here's how it's structured:

  ```js
  exports.functionName = functions
      .runWith({secrets: ['SECRET_KEY', "SECRET_KEY_TEST"]})
      .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
          // Code here.
  });
  ```
- There are no errors when the emulators start, which you'd expect if the configuration had a problem.

There is no mention of this being a limitation in the [functions docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#secrets_and_credentials_in_the_emulator). The [emulator docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#startup) mention the `--inspect-functions` flag causes a subtle behavior difference, but it doesn't seem relevant:

> Note that when this flag is supplied, the Cloud Functions emulator
> switches to a special serialized execution mode in which functions are
> executed in a single process, in sequential (FIFO) order; this
> simplifies function debugging, though the behavior differs from
> multi-process, parallel execution of functions in the cloud.

I'm running firebase-tools version 10.7.0 on Windows 10. ***Thanks for any assistance figuring this one out!***

Comment: @jktin12 - I didn't. I'm using a .secret.local file as a workaround.

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for responding though!

Comment: I haven't confirmed yet, but it seems this may be fixed: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4605